# Immutable.js ― custom getter method

Tags: javascript, getter, immutable.js

I've got a complex object with a lot of nested properties, and I frequently need to access some specific value. Rather than replicate the code for doing that every time, I would like to use a function. Is there a way to attach a method to an Immutable.js object, which would then return a specific value from that object? Or do I have to to use a separate function (i.e. `func(immObj)` rather than `immObj.get('func')()`)?

Comment: If the object is **immutable**, how do you expect to attach another method to it?

Comment: Immutable.fromJS({
      prop: 'propValue',
      method: () => {},
    };

I don't know, maybe it's obvious that something like that shouldn't work. But it seems to me like a custom getter of sorts would be useful, compared to a function that has to be imported every time you want to extract this one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [Record](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record)?

```
class ABRecord extends Record({a:1,b:2}) {
  getAB() {
    return this.a + this.b;
  }
}

var myRecord = new ABRecord({b: 3})
myRecord.getAB() // 4
```

Comment: I actually remember checking the `Record` but I guess official documentation didn't really explain what it does well enough for me. I read some more about it just now and it does seem like it solves my problem. More than that, it looks like a very useful feature that could be used instead of generic `Map`s in many places. Thanks!

Comment: Just beware if you decide to make the record nested.